# Mapping Business Hours

Tags: data-request, usa, business

I'm looking to map business hours for a given city in the USA to show the number of businesses open by time of day. Is there a way to get, at the least:

`{business name, business type, opening hours, location}`

for a particular area.

I looked at the [Yelp API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation) but I don't see:

1. How to get a dump for a particular area
2. Opening hours as a returned value

[Google Places - Places Details](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details) does have opening hours but it would appear that I first need to generate a list of all places of interest within my area.

Answer (score 8):

This CSV dataset contains opening-closing hours for thousands of US hotels/restaurants/bars/museums/etc:

https://github.com/baturin/wikivoyage-listings/

Business type, name and location are included as well.

You will need to filter out:

- Businesses that have no documented opening-closing hours
- Businesses that are not in the USA (there are columns for city name and latitude/longitude, you might use that)

Data license: Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0

Comment: Thank you! Good resource. Unfortunately I was looking at a lower-income neighbourhood, which is unlikely to be well documented on wikivoyage